# How to make a Dart socket wait for receiver to completely receive stream?

Tags: dart, sockets

I'm developing an API of which there is a Dart version and a Python version.  The API is used by clients to communicate with a server written in Python.  The problem I'm having is when sending a file from the client to the server.  The Python version of the API works as expected so I won't go into it much, but the file is read in chunks and sent like this:

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'rb') as f:
    chunkSize = 4096
    chunk = f.read(chunkSize)
    while chunk != b'':
        sock.sendall(chunk)
        chunk = f.read(chunkSize)
```

After the file has been completely sent by the client, the client listens on the same socket for a response from the server.

When I tried sending the file in chunks with Dart, the connection would fail in the middle of sending.  That was awhile back so I don't remember the exact error, but I found that I could use `addStream` instead of reading the file in chunks, and that mostly worked.  I say "mostly" because that solution required me to increase socket listen timeout which should not be necessary.  Here is the Dart code:

```
// Initialize socket with initial connection timeout of 3 seconds
Socket sock = await Socket.connect(ip, port, timeout: Duration(seconds: 3));

// Set socket listen timeout to 10 seconds
// A larger timeout is required for larger files
// A timeout of only 3 seconds works in all cases in the Python API
Stream<Uint8List> streamController = sock.timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: (sink) => sink.close());

// Send the file
File f = File('foobar.txt');
Stream<List<int>> stream = f.openRead();
await sock.addStream(stream);  // <--- I expect this to wait until the server socket has received all of the stream, but that isn't happening
      
StreamSubscription streamSubscription = streamController.listen((Uint8List receiveBufferChunk) async {
  // Do stuff with the server's response then close socket
  sock.close();
});

// Wait for the socket to be done listening for a response
await streamSubscription.asFuture<void>();
```

The problem is that `addStream` seems to return before the Python code on the server which I'm watching fully receives the file.  The server reads from the socket 4096 bytes at a time.

What is causing this and what can I do to make the Dart client socket behave like the Python client socket, and realize that the Python server hasn't yet received all the data on the stream?